# How to setup a robocall when your server is down?

Tags: monitoring, alerts

Is there a service that **calls you** (not just SMS) when your server is down?

We're using Pingdom for alerts, but it only alerts by SMS, which we sometimes miss.

Comment: Yeah, there are a bunch you can plug into an existing monitoring system or use as a monitoring system of their own.  Only ones I've seen with a phone call feature are pretty expensive (and a pain in the ass), though.

Comment: Why the vote to close?

Comment: I suspect it's because product and service recommendations are explicitly off-topic, as per the FAQ (which also links to an explanation of why).  I'm afraid I'm adding mine.

Comment: Why a call in a time everyone has a smartphone?

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Server-Monitoring/How-can-I-setup-a-robocall-when-my-server-goes-down

Answer (score 2):

The trick is not trying to find a service which would monitor and call but use a service which would monitor and e-mail. Feed this to a text2speech application capable of handling e-mail and you are done.

Numerous providers for reading mail using phone calls exist, so I suppose you should not have any trouble finding one that would cover your region and fit your needs.